# Java EE 7: Inject all instances of beans by name pattern

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, java-ee-7

I'd like to obtain all instances of beans which class name ends with `Cache`.

Is this possible in Java EE 7? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

You could inject [`BeanManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html):

```java
@Inject
BeanManager beanManager;
```

Then you can [get the beans](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#getBeans-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.annotation.Annotation...-) from the CDI container. If your beans don't have a common interface, you may use:

```java
Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(Object.class, new AnnotationLiteral<Any>() {}));
```

Then iterate over the set and filter it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using a producer method which retrieve beans of given type from `BeanManager` and filter it according to the class name

```
@Produces  
public List<MyInterface> produceMyInterfaces() {  
    return beanManager.getBeans(MyInterface.class).stream().filter(e -> e.getClass().getSimpleName().contains("something").collect(Collectors.toList());  
}
```